# How to use fstream in c++ in this situation?

Tags: c++

```
 #include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main () 

{

    int x;
    cout << "Pls. enter a natural number" << "\n" ;
    cin >> x ;
     cout  << "\n" ;
    for (int i=1 ; i<=x ; i++ )
    {
        x = x-1;
        cout << i << " " << x << "\n" ;
    }
    cout  << "\n" ;
    system ("pause");
    return 0;
} $
```

I have this sample code with cin first then cout.. my problem is that instead of the cout to output in the cmd it will be sent to a .txt file.. Where will I include the fstream codes.. thanks a lot...

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/5362783/390913

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<fstream>`:

```
#include <fstream>

// ...

std::ofstream ofs("output.txt");

ofs << "You said, " << n << "\n";
```

If you factor your printing code out, you can use either files or iostreams:

```
void print(std::ostream & o, int n) { o << "You said, " << n << "\n"; }

int main()
{
    int n = 11;
    std::ofstream ofs("output.txt");

    print(std::cout, n);
    print(ofs, n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple example to write in file.txt:

Don't forget include **fstream** header .

```
ofstream file;
file.open("c://file.txt",ios::out);
file << "Hello, this is test text.";
file.close();
```

And concerning your example see the code below

```
ofstream file;
file.open("c://file.txt",ios::out);

    int x;
    cout << "Pls. enter a natural number" << "\n" ;
    cin >> x ;
     cout  << "\n" ;
    for (int i=1 ; i<=x ; i++ )
    {
        x = x-1;
        file << i << " " << x << "\n" ;
    }
    file << "\n" ;
    file.close();
    system ("pause");
}
```

**The result:**
if you enter 5 , the result will be in the file:

> 1 4
>     2 3
>     3 2